# Determine orders of equations

Tags: asymptotics

$(1)$ Determine the order of the following expressions as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$
$$(i) \space ln [ 1+\frac{1+2\epsilon}{\epsilon(1-2\epsilon)} ]$$
$$(ii) \space \frac{1-cos \epsilon}{1+cos\epsilon}$$

My attempts:

$(1i) => ln[1+\frac{1+2\epsilon}{\epsilon - 2 \epsilon^2}]$
$=>\epsilon - 2\epsilon^2 \approx \epsilon$
$=>O(ln(\epsilon))$ or $O(\epsilon)$

$(1ii) =>$ no order? Since as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$
$=>\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-cos \epsilon}{1+cos\epsilon} = \frac{1-1}{1+1} = 0$

Comment: Are you supposed to know Taylor series ?

Comment: Yes we are, should I be expanding the cos?

Comment: It could be a good idea ! Later, long division.